# Wordpress and TinyMCE Advanced: Failed to load javascript

Tags: tinymce

When I change `WP_PLUGIN_DIR` example:

```
define( 'WP_PLUGIN_DIR', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/../wp-content/renamefolder' );
```

All plugins are shown and I can activate them.
[image]

But with TinyMCE Advanced when I wrote post, alert message shows 
[image]

> Failed to load plugin: insertdatetime from url ../../wp-content/plugins/tinymce-advanced/mce/insertdatetime/plugin.min.js

How to change code in `tinymce-advanced.php` or how to fix it?

Comment: easiest way to fix it is not to change the plugin dir in the first place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`WP_PLUGIN_DIR` customizes the location of files in filesystem.

Most likely you *also* need to customize `WP_PLUGIN_URL`, which customizes client–facing URL location. If you omit this one, WP will decide it based on `WP_CONTENT_URL`, which might not at all point to your new location.

Another possibility is that plugin/code in question simply *cannot* handle a custom location. Generally this shouldn't happen under a normal WP API usage and such should be reported to developers as a possible bug.

Comment: It means I can't rename folder `plugins` right? @Rarst

Comment: You can?.. I don't see how that would follow out of my answer.

Comment: I changed code in function wp_plugin_directory_constants()  `default-constants.php` and it's working.really fun

Comment: You shouldn't ever change core files. You should properly configure this with constants, as per answer.

Comment: I put this code in wp-config.php
http://i.imgur.com/JAe99TT.png
And I realized when I updated wordpress core, this code in file `default-constants.php` will be deleted..I laughed at yourself..Thank you

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem an copied the en.js to de.js and voila - it works.

for some reason tinymce seams to ignore the language and defaults to en